# ArcGIS API for JavaScript Bookmark in separate Div

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, bookmarks

Using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript I need to create a number of different bookmarks and access them through the HTML in separate div tags.  I created this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bretwhiteley/3ae7573c/) in attempt.

I thought that if I defined separate bookmarks and bookmarkitems, it would work.  No success yet.  I think I am close, missing something simple/.

```
      var bookmark1 = new esri.dijit.Bookmarks({
      map: map, 
      bookmarks: Bookmark_1

    }, dojo.byId('Bookmark1'));
```